# (Django) Does MySQL foreign key cascade delete parent or children first

Tags: python, mysql, django

Currently, I am using Django with a MySQL backend database.

Let us having the following database schema

```
class Parent(models.Model):
     parent_id  = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
     last_child = models.ForeignKey('Child', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Child(models.Model):
     child_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
     parent   = models.ForeignKey('Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Each parent can have multiple children, but each child can only have one parent. The field `last_child` points to the last child birthed by the parent. What I am trying to express via this schema is

- The last child cannot die (be deleted) as long as its parent is still alive
- All children die when the parent dies

However I have some concerns regarding database integrity, because of the conflicting `PROTECT` vs `CASCADE`.

**My question is, what will MySQL attempt to delete first should I delete `Parent`? Will it delete `Parent` first then try to delete the `Child` rows, or the other way around?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `Django` does when you delete an object -> It deletes all children first, and then deletes the object.

Your schema is a little bit strange, you need to make your `last_child` object `null-able`, because how are you gonna create a `parent` without `children` ?

You can't create a `child` without a `parent`, and you can't create a `parent` with a `last_child`.

So when you make your `last_child` null-able, on `parent.delete` you need to set `last_child = null`, and then call `parent.delete()`. And I guess you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As for your concern for nullability, that was a simple error on my part for forgetting to put that in. I have solved my problem now with your help